# How to get data from the docs folder in my github repository? It shows no directory when I tried deploying the application

Tags: python, pdf, github, path

[image]
I have added pdf files in the docs folder here

[image]

I need to add the path of the docs folder to my app.py file

[image]
When i add the path it show directory doesnt exist it . how do i correctly add the path to my my app.py file help please?

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be with the path. You are trying to access files that are in the `docs` folder but have the path as `guidenlines/docs/`.

Changing the code to look like this should solve your problem:

```
df = pdf_converter(directory_path="./docs/")
```

I would also suggest using the os module, it will allow for interoperability between different operating systems. A few links for your reference ([Link 1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), [Link 2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_path_methods.htm)).

As for what I can observe right now, using the following code should suffice your use case:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

docs_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "docs")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is in a public SVN thus you could access it easily via URL
https://github.com/hebaarch/guidenlines/tree/main/docs

OR provide links to individual docs like this

https://github.com/hebaarch/guidenlines/raw/main/docs/FIRE%20AND%20LIFE%20SAFETY%20CODE_Page24.pdf

https://github.com/hebaarch/guidenlines/blob/main/docs/FIRE%20AND%20LIFE%20SAFETY%20CODE_Page24.pdf
[image]

Hovever to make manipulation easy on yourself its easiest to pull a copy with curl to a local folder using

`curl -o c:\myFolder\Page24.pdf http://blah blah_Page24.pdf`

then either discard or if changed for updating use Git to Push

**OR much simpler Drag and Drop the new version onto the old**